# SDTT error: "Service is not a known valid target type for the itemReviewed property"

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets

Using the following HTML+RDFa:

```html
<div vocab="https://schema.org/" typeof="Service">
        <meta property="name" content="My Service Name"/>
        <div property="description">
            For verified ratings of our services, please view our:
            <a
                href="https://www.capterra.com/link/to/captera"
                target="_blank"
            >4.9 Star Rating on Capterra</a>
        </div>
        <div property="aggregateRating" typeof="AggregateRating">
            <div>
                Capterra Rating:
                <span property="ratingValue">4.9</span> out of
                <span property="bestRating">5</span> with
                <span property="ratingCount">112</span> ratings
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This snippet is in my code, but when I test it all in Google's [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/?authuser=0), I get the following error:

[image]

I'm having trouble accepting this error because (if i'm reading this correctly), according to the [`Service` docs](https://schema.org/Service) in https://schema.org/, this is a supported property. I'm sure there is a syntax error somewhere or, if I dare touch the sun, Google is wrong.

I ran it through the [structured data](http://linter.structured-data.org/) and it recognized it:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You are not doing anything wrong.**

On 16th Sep 2019, Google [tweaked](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2019/09/making-review-rich-results-more-helpful.html) their rich snippets requirements, wherein the `itemReviewed` property is now supported only for a very small list of Schema.org types.

As per Google:

> While, technically, you can attach review markup to any schema type,
>   for many types displaying star reviews does not add much value for the
>   user. With this change, we’re limiting the pool of schema types that
>   can potentially trigger review rich results in search. Specifically,
>   we’ll only display reviews with those types (and their respective
>   subtypes)...

Earlier, `CreativeWork`, `Article`, `BlogPosting`, `Service` were all supported and there was no error message on the structured data testing tool.

Now, any schema other than the list below will trigger a '_______  is not a known valid target type for the itemReviewed property.' error.

The valid types for the `itemReviewed` property are:

- `Book`
- `ListItem`
- `Course`
- `CreativeWorkSeason`
- `CreativeWorkSeries`
- `Episode`
- `Event`
- `Game`
- `HowTo`
- `LocalBusiness`
- `MediaObject`
- `Movie`
- `MusicPlaylist`
- `MusicRecording`
- `Organization`
- `Product`
- `Recipe`
- `SoftwareApplication`

**Note :** There are other schema types that are valid and may not trigger an error message on the testing tool for aggregateRating or itemReviewed. However, from the Google Blog posting, I understand it as 'Even if the schema is valid, stars / rich snippets may not show up for schemas other than those specifically listed.'

Comment: I want to add, while not displayed in the list, `WebApplication` seems to work too as Google's tool doesn't complain about it, which is what I ended up using.

Comment: WebApplication is a sub type of SoftwareApplication so is implicitly also supported.